JSON Schema how to create condition over patternProperties
we have subnet names as keys in subnets map. I want create schema to make subnet name length restricted conditional based on vpc_access key which is nested in the subnet.
I know that it is possible to make condition on nested property via properties.PROPERTY1.properties.PROPERTY2.const.VALUE, but in my case I do not know the exact property name because I'm using patternProperties.
So I'm trying to do something like this. It is JSON schema written in yaml form.
subnets:
  if:
    patternProperties:
      ^.*$:
        properties:
          vpc_access:
            const: true
        required:
          - vpc_access
  then:
    propertyNames:
      pattern: ^[a-z][a-z0-9-]{1,22}[a-z0-9]$
  patternProperties:
    ^.*$:
      $ref: /schemas/network.subnet

Can you please confirm if this is possible in schema and help how to do it, please?

So, there are two types of subnets, one with vpc_access=true and a property key matching the length-restricting regex, and without vpc_access=true and no length restriction.  Does an object contain a heterogeneous mix of the two types, or homogeneous and every subnet in a given object is the same type?

patternProperties will only evaluate keys that match the pattern. Otherwise, any other property will be evaluated based on other parts of the schema, or ignored all together depending on the constraints of your schema
in this example, anything matching the pattern will expect an object with a required key vpc_access: true. Otherwise, any other properties not matching the pattern will require whatever the network.subnet schema is.
properties:
  subnets:
    patternProperties:
      '^[a-z][a-z0-9-]{1,22}[a-z0-9]$':
        type: object
        properties:
          vpc_access:
            type: boolean
            const: true
        required:
          - vpc_access
    additionalProperties:
      $ref: '#/$defs/network.subnet'
$defs:
  network.subnet: {}

if you are trying to evaluate the value of vpc_access to enforce the key length, it's not possible to evaluate a nested value for a parent key.
On the other hand, if your data instance is expecting vpc_access: true and the key length to match the pattern, if the key matches the pattern and the value of vpc_access is false, the instance will fail validation because you are constraining the schema to only allow const: true, effectively giving you a similar output to your request.
